# on change event is not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-select2

I'm working on a small Angular app, and when my page loads I want to retrieve a value from my select2 dropdown. Here is my code:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {

console.log("this happen?");

if (this._globals.isAdmin === false) {
  console.log("first condition is executed cuz logged in user is not admin?")
  $('#selected-user').val(this.person[0].id).trigger('change');
}
else {
  $('#selected-user').val(this.helper.emptyGuid()).trigger('change');
}

// This is not executed
$('#selected-user').on(
  'change',
  (e) => {
    this.searchQuery.personId = $(e.target).val().toString();
    console.log("This is not executed when page loads:", this.searchQuery.personId);
  });
}
```

Here is the result from console.log:

[image]

As you can see even if I set `$('#selected-user').val(this.person[0].id).trigger('change');` in first condition it didn't executed. How come?

Comment: add your .html file code where select is located

Comment: avoid jquery in angular that is not best practice angular have its on event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular native events insted of jquery:

Refer:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nzd4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

app.component.html

```
<select (change)="selectUserChange($event)">
  <option value="User-1">User-1</option>
  <option value="User-2">User-2</option>
  <option value="User-3">User-3</option>
  <option value="User-4">User-4</option>
</select>

<p *ngIf="currentSelectedUser">Current Selecte user is: {{currentSelectedUser}}</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  currentSelectedUser:any;

  selectUserChange(event){
    let selecetedItem=event.target.value;
    this.currentSelectedUser=selecetedItem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using angular, why you are not using ng-change. Try to follow the standards. If you are creating an angular app try to use every functionality of angular only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write change events in angular. You can just bind your dropdown with a property and use a change event to call a function which can set you parameters to searhQuery. This is what I am suggesting.

```
selectedPersonId: any;
constructor(private dashBoardService: DashboardService) {
    if (this._globals.isAdmin === false) {
      console.log("first condition is executed cuz logged in user is not admin?")
      this.selectedPersonId = this.person[0].id;
    }
    else {
        this.selectedPersonId = this.helper.emptyGuid();
    }
    this.searchQuery.personId = this.selectedPersonId;
}
changePerson(){
    this.searchQuery.personId = this.selectedPersonId;
}
```

and then use changePerson on your dropdown like `(change)="changePerson()"`.

```
<select (change)="changePerson()" [(ngModel)]="selectedPersonId">
```